# Pushing requests to a HandlerStack after Guzzle Client has been created

Tags: mocking, phpunit, handler, guzzle

I’m trying to send fake requests — for unit testing — after my Guzzle Client (v6) has been created.

I tried to look in Guzzle classes for a while but I cannot find a way to achieve this. Please note that I'm in a PHPUnit test and **can only access the client**, sent by another test it depends on.

```
// Create a mock and queue two responses.
$mock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar']),
    new Response(202, ['Content-Length' => 0])
]);

$handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
$client = new Client(['handler' => $handler]);

// New requests after the client has been initiated
$newMock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar']),
    new Response(202, ['Content-Length' => 0])
]);

// useful?
$config  = $client->getConfig();
$handler = $config['handler'];

// push the new requests in $newMock?
$handler->something(…);
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost there. For your last line:

```
$handler->setHandler($newMock);
```

Comment: Sorry - just noticed the age of this question. Came across this whilst searching for an answer to a similar issue about HandlerStack

Comment: Still usefull! Will try if I go back working on this! Thanks!